# App Store Connect Operation Error ITMS-90534

Tags: ios, macos, sdk, app-store

App Store Connect Operation Error
Error ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built with an unsupported SDK or version of Xcode. If you plan to submit this build to the App store,
make sure you are using the version listed in https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf16aefe3b or later."

***I don't know what they're saying. I have the latest Xcode and the latest mac os.***

[Vie the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vULQY.jpg)